# How to wait till the current acitivity is in progress

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating a test case which will check for the Android application.

1. It launches the application.
2. It enters the user and pass.

I need to check whether it is logged in or not. For that I am trying to get the current activity. If it is logged in, it will show the next activity if not it will show the home activity itself.

How to get the current activity or help me in doing this above mentioned option.

Comment: Post code please. It's difficult to know exactly what you mean otherwise. Specifically, do you have a simple boolean condition to check if the user is logged in? What do these activities look like?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) . It's a UI testing framework for android and it's very easy to use. It also allows you to wait until an activity / text / etc. appears on the screen.